# Soap is not detected by Magento 2

Tags: magento2, soap

In my Magento Admin panel when I entering in a section, looks like is not detecting *soap* extension like this:

[image]

But in my *phpinfo* is enabled:

[image]

The specific section is *licenses* from a extension called *venustheme*

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you using php-fpm?

Comment: Yes @DianaBotean

Comment: Try to restart php-fpm. Maybe you missed a restart/ reload after enabling soap extension.

Comment: The soap always been in the server, even before megamenu installation, once it were installed; the service was reloaded and rebooted several times with any success... I was thinking my megamenu extension is for Magento 2.3.x and my composer.json says my magento version is 2.4; but I've other project with same version only changes the subversion. The ambient with the issue has 2.4.2, and my other ambient shows 2.4.1 It should be any fact about version?

Comment: In this case, I would suggest you check with the module's vendor and see if the compatibility is granted.

Comment: Thank you @DianaBotean!

Comment: no problem, anytime :) good luck!